# State whether the sequence $\ln n - \ln(n+1)$ converges and, if it does, find the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I know that the limit as n approaches infinity of 
$\ln n - \ln(n+1)$ would be $0$.

Does that mean its convergent? My professor is pretty strict on proving these, so is there a more strenuous way to demonstrate this?

Comment: Can you use the continuity of logarithm? If yes, then it simply follows from the fact that $\ln(n)-\ln(n+1)=\ln(\frac{n}{n+1})=\ln(1-\frac{1}{n+1})$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ln{(n)}-\ln{(n+1)})=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln{\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)}=\ln{\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\right)}=\ln{(1)}=0$$
Where one can justify the exchange of functional application and taking the limit because the function $\ln{(x)}$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [basic bound](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_Bound_of_Natural_Logarithm) for logarithm $ 1-\frac{1}{x} \leq \ln x$ for $x>0$ and the fact that $\ln$ is increasing, we have
$$
-\frac{1}{n}=1-\frac{n+1}{n} \leq \ln\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right) \leq \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n+1}\right)=\ln 1 = 0
$$
and now just use [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

1)$\log n -\log n(1+1/n)=$

$ \log n -\log n -\log (1+1/n)=$

$-\log (1+1/n)$;

2) MVT :

$0< \log (1+1/n)=$

$\displaystyle{\int_{1}^{1+1/n}}(1/x)dx=$

$(1/t)(1/n)<1/n,$ where   $1 \le t \le (1+1/n)$;

The limit is ?